# vNext / .NET5 config.json in wwwroot

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

So far as i am thinking, it is now preferred to use config.json files to store configuration settings for you application, which is great.  Love json format and find it easier to read.

Upon publishing my first vNext application though, i notice that the config.json file seems to publish into

`approot/src/my_project/config.json`

and my website are in a folder called `wwwroot`

My web server has multiple websites setup and each one used to have its own "app.config" file, which i could put in the website directory with settings specific to that website being run.  But now i have 2 problems,

1. config.json is populated into the wrong directory
2. If i do put the config.json file into the wwwroot folder, then it can be accessed by the client via the browser. This is very dangerous.

Do i have to setup my web server to ignore requests for config.json if its in wwwroot, or am i missing something completely?

Comment: Do not place the config.json in the wwwroot. That's the whole point of having a separate wwwroot folder. It's easier to keep it from being served out if you don't put it in the folder that gets served out.

Comment: So it should go in the wwwroot then?  What about users being able to see it when you browse to it though?

Comment: No, it should *not* be in the wwwroot.

Comment: Then how can you have a configuration per site like you could in previous MVC versions? If it is not in the root because that gets published to approot, and its not in wwwroot, which is for use on each separate site, where can it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to mason for his answer about structuring websites on your webserver with regards to vNext, but there is also another option worth mentioning here, that is why i have add another answer.

As stated above, i have the config.json file in my project for developing, and to get the file i was using this in my Startup.cs file

```
public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath.)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

This includes the file in the approot when publishing.  Including it in the wwwroot is not an option either.  So using the file structure, where you would have a folder containing both the approot and wwwroot folders, i changed the code to this, which works for development and publishing.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // configuration is in the folder above the wwwroot
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(env.MapPath("..\\"))
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

However, when you publish the code/site, the config.json file is still put in the approot folder.  To get round this, you must can it to the project.json file, like so

```
"publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "config.json",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
],
"exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "config.json",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
]
```

Now the file can be in the project root so you can save it too source control, it works when using IIS Express for developing and it is not published either.

Hope this help someone else

Answer (score 2):

You should have a separate folder for each project. And never place a folder in wwwroot that you don't want served out. It could end up looking something like this:

```
/root
/root/Project1
/root/Project1/config.json
/root/Project1/wwwroot
/root/Project2
/root/Project2/config.json
/root/Project2/wwwwroot
```

Obviously, your structure doesn't have to exactly match. In general though, if you use separate directories to separate your projects, and don't put your config in your wwwroot, you'll be fine.

By the way, you may want to avoid having anything secret in the config.json file in the first place. You *should be* using source code control software, and you should avoid a situation where secret stuff gets checked in. Perhaps environment variables or the [secrets API](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-Secret-Configuration).

Comment: I have connectionStrings and application specific settings in my config.json, just like web.config file had before. In your example structure, where is approot? Also when developing where could i possibly store the config.json file? Sorry but all examples on web, have config.json in root, so just trying to get head around it all

Comment: @user2736022 It's wherever you want it to be. A logical place seems like `/root/Project1/approot/` It's up to you.

Comment: I didnt know if i was just missing something regarding file structure in vNext. Thanks again